# Why doesn't my web-crawling method find all the links?

Tags: ruby, web-crawler, nokogiri

I'm trying to create a simple web-crawler, so I wrote this:

(Method `get_links` take a parent link from which we will seek)

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

def get_links(link)
    link = "http://#{link}"
    doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(link))
    links = doc.css('a')
    hrefs = links.map {|link| link.attribute('href').to_s}.uniq.delete_if {|href| href.empty?}
    array = hrefs.select {|i| i[0] == "/"}
    host = URI.parse(link).host
    links_list = array.map {|a| "#{host}#{a}"}
end
```

(Method `search_links`, takes an array from `get_links` method and search at this array)

```
def search_links(urls)
    urls = get_links(link)
    urls.uniq.each do |url|
        begin
            links = get_links(url)
            compare = urls & links
            urls << links - compare
            urls.flatten!
        rescue OpenURI::HTTPError
            warn "Skipping invalid link #{url}"
        end
    end
    return urls
end
```

This method finds most of links from the website, but not all.

What did I do wrong? Which algorithm I should use?

Comment: Please provide a short HTML document in which a link isn't found by your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some comments about your code:

```
  def get_links(link)
    link = "http://#{link}"
    # You're assuming the protocol is always http.
    # This isn't the only protocol on used on the web.

    doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(link))

    links = doc.css('a')
    hrefs = links.map {|link| link.attribute('href').to_s}.uniq.delete_if {|href| href.empty?}
    # You can write these two lines more compact as
    #   hrefs = doc.xpath('//a/@href').map(&:to_s).uniq.delete_if(&:empty?)

    array = hrefs.select {|i| i[0] == "/"}
    # I guess you want to handle URLs that are relative to the host.
    # However, URLs relative to the protocol (starting with '//')
    # will also be selected by this condition.

    host = URI.parse(link).host
    links_list = array.map {|a| "#{host}#{a}"}
    # The value assigned to links_list will implicitly be returned.
    # (The assignment itself is futile, the right-hand-part alone would
    # suffice.) Because this builds on `array` all absolute URLs will be
    # missing from the return value.
  end
```

Explanation for

```
hrefs = doc.xpath('//a/@href').map(&:to_s).uniq.delete_if(&:empty?)
```

- `.xpath('//a/@href')` uses the attribute syntax of XPath to directly get to the `href` attributes of `a` elements
- `.map(&:to_s)` is an abbreviated notation for `.map { |item| item.to_s }`
- `.delete_if(&:empty?)` uses the same abbreviated notation

And comments about the second function:

```
def search_links(urls)
    urls = get_links(link)
    urls.uniq.each do |url|
      begin
        links = get_links(url)


        compare = urls & links
        urls << links - compare
        urls.flatten!
        # How about using a Set instead of an Array and
        # thus have the collection provide uniqueness of
        # its items, so that you don't have to?


      rescue OpenURI::HTTPError
         warn "Skipping invalid link #{url}"
      end
    end
    return urls
    # This function isn't recursive, it just calls `get_links` on two
    # 'levels'. Thus you search only two levels deep and return findings
    # from the first and second level combined. (Without the "zero'th"
    # level - the URL passed into `search_links`. Unless off course if it
    # also occured on the first or second level.)
    #
    # Is this what you intended?
  end
```

Comment: This all seems like good feedback, but it's hard to tell if there's an actual answer to the question. Could you please make the answer more clear?

Comment: @skrrgwasme, I can only give a clearer answer if the asker provides some data (HTTP documents to be scraped) that demonstrate how their current code fails their expectations. Otherwise I can only guess what links it might miss. If you see a way my answer can be improved without that, feel free to edit it or to provide an answer of your own.

Comment: I only mentioned it because your answer showed up in the Low Quality Post Review Queue, so someone has flagged it, and I suspect it's because it is hard to tell if it really answers the question or not. If you don't make an answer more clear, it may get deleted.

Comment: thank you for the answer, but is it not what I intended.How I can write a recursive method and find links from the all 'levels'?

Comment: It's not necessary, or idiomatic, to use the block form of `open` with Nokogiri. The file will be closed after reading.

Comment: Thanks, @theTinMan, I wasn't aware of that. I've now deleted that remark from the commented code. Is the implicit closing after reading something special Nokogiri does, or is this just the effect of ["I/O streams are automatically closed when they are claimed by the garbage collector."](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/IO.html#method-i-close) when the only references to `open`'s return value is the one passed to `Nokogiri::HTML`, so that only reference will be garbage collected as soon as Nokogiri gives up that reference?

Comment: During garbage collection. I ran a test using a simple script that opens a file, passes the opened file's handle to Nokogiri, then ran `lsof` to look for the open file handle in the OS, then stepped through the handoff to Nokogiri, and the file was still open after Nokogiri returned control. Open file handles are usually closed when Ruby exits at the end of the script, not when the garbage handler processes. Since most Nokogiri scripts only read a single file it's not an issue, only when reading enough files to use up the OS's file-handle pool.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably be using mechanize:

```
require 'mechanize'
agent = Mechanize.new
page = agent.get url
links = page.search('a[href]').map{|a| page.uri.merge(a[:href]).to_s}
# if you want to remove links with a different host (hyperlinks?)
links.reject!{|l| URI.parse(l).host != page.uri.host}
```

Otherwise you'll have trouble converting relative urls to absolute properly.